# How much sugar should be added in 1 L of Grape must?

Tags: red-wine, measurements

I get that most of homebrewers make large batches and they measure it in gallons, but how do I shrink the recipe measurements if I will ferment just one liter of grape juice?

Answer (score 1):

**Scaling is very simple math and works with all ingredients.**

For example if a recipe is for 1 gallon and calls for 4 oz of sugar. 
1 Gallon has 3.79 liters, so 1/3.79=.2638 that's your volume %
To scale the sugar 4×.2638=1.055 oz sugar for 1 liter.

You don't have to be so precise, 1oz sugar in this example is close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like Beersmith ($) or Brewers Friend (Free) allow you to create a standard 5 gallon recipe then scale it up or down.

Link for brewers friend's calculator:
[Brewers Friend](https://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/calculator)